# Gradient Descent Algorithm for Interdependent parameters

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

Suppose I have $n$ data points ($X_i$,$y_i$) where $X_i$ is a vector and $y_i$ is a scalar, $1 \le i \le n$. By defining $\hat{\boldsymbol{Y}} =  \boldsymbol{\Theta} \boldsymbol{X} + \boldsymbol{b}$ and defining the cost (risk) function as $\mathcal{L} =  || \boldsymbol{Y} - \hat{\boldsymbol{Y}} ||$ we can use gradient descent algorithm to optimize (approximately) $\boldsymbol{\Theta}$.

But **I think** the presumption in this formulation is that all parameters (all elements in $\boldsymbol{\Theta}_{n \times n}$) are independent means that changing $\Theta_{ij}$ does not affect other parameters. However, I have a formulated problem in which some elements in $\boldsymbol{\Theta}_{n \times n}$ are repeated. Precisely, $\boldsymbol{\Theta}_{n \times n}$ is a symmetric matrix, i.e., $\forall 1 \le i,j \le n: \boldsymbol{\Theta}_{ij} = \boldsymbol{\Theta}_{ji}$.

Now my question is if there is any variation of gradient descent algorithm that can be applied for this problem?

Comment: We do not assume that the parameters are independent. If anything we accept that they have non-diagonal covariance that we use to calculate their standard error.

Comment: So you mean I can still use gradient-Descent when $\Theta$ is symmetric. (Maybe I had not used the interdependent word because my parameters are actually repeated.)

Comment: Your parameters can be taken to be the $\Theta_{ij}$ for $i\le j.$  There are no constraints among them. Insisting on the symmetry of $\Theta,$ though, is a little strange.  Could you tell us what the statistical application might be?

Comment: Ok, suppose I have a weighted undirected graph and the weights of the edges are our parameters and have to be optimized based on a specific risk function $\mathcal{L}$. In this case, I have a symmetric matrix of parameters.

Comment: From *purely an optimization perspective,* this sounds like a job for projected gradient descent (PGD; compare w/ gradient descent [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571068/what-is-the-difference-between-projected-gradient-descent-and-ordinary-gradient)), or even [mirror descent with Von Neumann divergence (see slide 5-18)](https://www.princeton.edu/~yc5/ele522_optimization/lectures/mirror_descent.pdf). PGD is gradient descent with an extra projection step onto your constraints. However, I'm not sure what implications this has on the statistical properties of your estimator.